# Is there a way for me to change an image that is being displayed by hovering on an icon link using strictly CSS & HTML

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4

I have an image that is being displayed (in a col-8) to the right of 4 icons and a paragraph (in a col-4) I want the formatting of this page to remain the same. I want the image that is linked to the first icon to display automatically when the page loads, and the four other images to display in place of the first image when the user hovers over the other three icons.

If anybody could give me a solution or even just the link to a video/article they think will help I'd be very appreciative. I deleted the code from the svg icons because it made the html more difficult to read and was too many characters to upload but you get the idea.  [image: what the page looks like now]

HTML

```
<div class="container-right">
            <div class="row pb-5 pt-3">
                <div class="col-4 ">
                    <h1 class="pb-2 text-center text-md-left">Products</h1>
                    <b>Customer satisfaction is a top priority. At Hills Industrial, we want our customers to be astounded with the choices we offer, excited by the innovation we provide and satisfied with our service and reliability. Providing superior customer experience in a consistent manner is our primary goal.</b>
                    <div class="row mt-4">
                        <!-- Controls -->
                        <div class="col-5">
                            <a href="#"><div class="icon-background"><svg class="product-icon" </svg></div></a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Pump -->
                        <div class="col-5">
                            <a href="#"><div class="icon-background"><svg class="product-icon" </svg></div></a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Power Transmission -->
                        <div class="col-5">
                            <a href="#"><div class="icon-background"><svg class="product-icon" 
                                </svg></div></a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Motor -->
                        <div class="col-5">    
                            <a href="#"><div class="icon-background"><svg class="product-icon" </svg></div></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <img src="img/motor-stock.jpg" class="product-photo"></img>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.product-icon{
  width:50px;
  fill: #ffff;
  transition:fill 0.3s ease-out;
}

 .icon-background:hover .product-icon{
  fill: #fb0203;
}

.product-photo{
  border-radius:400px 0px 0px 400px ;
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
}

.container-right {
  padding-left: 15px;
  /* padding-right: 15px; */
}
@media (min-width:576px){
.container-right {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: calc(50vw - 270px);
}
}

@media (min-width:768px){
.container-right {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: calc(50vw - 360px);
}
}

@media (min-width:992px){
.container-right {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: calc(50vw - 480px);
}
}

@media (min-width:1200px){
.container-right {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: calc(50vw - 570px);
}
}

.icon-background{
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
  padding:15px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin:10px;
  border: 2px solid #e10001;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without delving too deep into your code, the general idea is not using an `img` tag and instead set the image as a `background-image` on the div; also, find a way to put the links on the same level as the image div, that way you can use the [sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) to change the image.

Here's an idea using [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) (images taken from https://kaboompics.com):

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "content content image image"
    "link1 link2 image image"
    "link3 link4 image image";
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
}

.link {
  display: inline-grid;
  place-content: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.link:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

#link-1 {
  grid-area: link1;
}

#link-2 {
  grid-area: link2;
}

#link-3 {
  grid-area: link3;
}

#link-4 {
  grid-area: link4;
}

.image {
  grid-area: image;
  background-image: url("https://kaboompics.com/cache/8/4/3/a/0/843a085ea22499ba621d5808a4f33fba35045a6d.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
  width: 700px;
}

#link-1:hover ~ .image {
  background-image: url("https://kaboompics.com/cache/d/1/9/b/2/d19b234473ad74fce320c208f5e0f8ddfc20d1f3.jpeg");
}

#link-2:hover ~ .image {
  background-image: url("https://kaboompics.com/cache/b/d/b/1/b/bdb1b249aacef7ebcb74a4ffd66f211f9abd98c0.jpeg");
}

#link-3:hover ~ .image {
  background-image: url("https://kaboompics.com/cache/4/3/a/a/c/43aac8eb9d62e85b1f99e916384d08f498bb4810.jpeg");
}

#link-4:hover ~ .image {
  background-image: url("https://kaboompics.com/cache/5/c/6/d/f/5c6dfadb3207b778e2d8478b2502781f7220592f.jpeg");
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1 class="pb-2 text-center text-md-left">Products</h1>
    <p>Customer satisfaction is a top priority. At Hills Industrial, we want our customers to be astounded with the choices we offer, excited by the innovation we provide and satisfied with our service and reliability. Providing superior customer experience in a consistent manner is our primary goal.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="link" id="link-1">Link 1</div>
  <div class="link" id="link-2">Link 2</div>
    <div class="link" id="link-3">Link 3</div>
    <div class="link" id="link-4">Link 4</div>
  
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Good luck!

**Edit:** As noted in [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Images_in_HTML#css_background_images), the use of CSS images should be reserved only to those cases where the image doesn't have a semantic meaning (i.e the image is only for decoration), so if your images have a meaning in terms of content - I would suggest you to use `img` tags and control their visibility with JavaScript.

Comment: Is this in some way dependent on the grid system to work? I tried to implement what you did here using my bootstrap-4  12-col grid layout that I had already created and am finding that the images aren't changing on hover.

Comment: Yes, in some way. The important point is for the links to be siblings of the image div, because I'm using the `~` selector to refer to the div when the links are hovered. I'm using the grid system to help me position them, you can use whichever method works for you of course :)